# 1k entries query with multiple JOIN's takes up to 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, left-join, performance

Here's a simplified version of the structure (left out some regular varchar cols):

```
CREATE TABLE `car` (
 `reg_plate` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
 `type` text NOT NULL,
 `client` int(11) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`reg_plate`)
)
```

And here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    car.*,
    tire.id as tire,
    client.name as client_name
FROM 
    car
        LEFT JOIN client ON car.client = client.id
        LEFT JOIN tire ON tire.reg_plate = reg_plate
GROUP BY car.reg_plate
) t1
```

The nested query is necessary due to the framework sometimes adding WHERE / SORT clauses (which assume there are columns named `client_name` or `tire`). 
Both the `car` and the `tire` tables have approx. 1,5K entries. `client` has no more than 500, and for some reason it still takes up to 10 seconds to complete (worse, the framework runs it twice, first to check how much rows there are, then to actually limit to the requested page)

I'm getting a feeling that this query is very inefficient, I just don't know how to optimize it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation?  This is one of the worst "features" of `MySQL...`

Comment: What indexes do you have? Can you do an `EXPLAIN` on your query and post the results here?

Comment: Try putting "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" in the front of your query and post the results.

Comment: ...and provide the structure of the other tables in the query

Comment: @JNK otherwise, there'll be multiple rows for one car. Do I need to add for example a count(car.reg_plate) to the select clause?

Comment: @Cookie - there are a **LOT** of potential issues from this practice, not least of which you get random rows for all your ungrouped columns.  It may work OK in your example but can cause issues in other places, so be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read up on [MySQL's EXPLAIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

You probably need indexes on every column in the join clauses, and on every column that your framework uses in WHERE and SORT clauses. Sometimes multi-column indexes are better than single-column indexes.

Your framework probably doesn't require nested queries. Unnesting and creating a view or passing parameters to a stored procedure might give you better performance.

For better suggestions on SO, always include DDL and sample data (as INSERT statements) in your questions. You should probably include EXPLAIN output on performance questions, too.

Comment: Wow! Indexing those columns indeed dropped the execution time from 10 to 0,1 seconds :D thanks (sorry for not being able to figure that out by myself, I still need to gather some more knowledge on databases.)